# Python & Tensorflow & CUDA Environment Setup Problems

Tags: python-3.x, windows-10, tensorflow2.0, nsight-compute, nsight-systems

I **had** tensorflow 2.2 working with Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit yesterday, including using the GPU. This morning, the same system no longer sees the GPU. I have uninstalled/reinstalled CUDA, 
& the other requirements based on the tensorflow docs but it just refuses to work.

PC specs: i7 CPU 3.70GHz, 64GB RAM, NVidia GeForce GTX 780 Ti video card installed (driver 26.21.14.4122).

https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu says tensorflow requires NVidia CUDA Toolkit 10.1 **specifically** (not 10.0, not 10.2).

Naturally, that version refuses to install on my PC. these components fail during install:

- Visual Studio Integration
- NSight Systems
- NSight Compute

So, I installed 10.2 which installs properly, but things don't run (which is not a surprise, given the tensorflow docs).

What's installed:

```
$ nvidia-smi
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 441.22       Driver Version: 441.22       CUDA Version: 10.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780 Ti WDDM  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 27%   41C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    458MiB /  3072MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
$ nvcc --version
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Oct_23_19:32:27_Pacific_Daylight_Time_2019
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.2, V10.2.89
```

I know the nvcc output of 10.2.89 is not what I need, but it simply won't install 10.1 so I don't know what I can do. Is this a common problem? Is there a diagnostic I can run to ensure the card did not die? Should I downgrade my version of tensorflow? Should I abandon this environment all together? Is so, what is a **stable** environment to learn ML?

Comment: There are two versions of cuda 10.1 (the [original](https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.0/Prod/local_installers/cuda_10.0.130_411.31_win10) and the [updated one](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/10.1/Prod/local_installers/cuda_10.1.243_426.00_win10.exe)) Have ya tried both? Also you did not mention why it refuses to install -- that is the error stack trace ?

Comment: This was helpful.  cuda_10.1.243_win10_network.exe Express Install --> WORKED. Thank you for keeping me going in the right direction. Still not working with Tensorflow (yet), but it feels like progress.

Comment: Sweet mother of god this is working again.  

This is how I got it working:  

Uninstall every bit of NVIDIA software.  

Express Install cuda_10.1.243_win10_network.exe  

Extract cudnn-10.1-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32 into the CUDA file structure  

Add to path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin

Add to path: C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp  

Reboot

Uninstall all tensorflow variants via PIP

Install tensorflow (2.2, in my case) via PIP`

Comment: That's great, happy to help. Please answer your own question for future readers and accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is how I got it working. Tensorflow 2.2.0, Windows 10, Python 3.7 (64-bit). Thanks again to Yahya for the gentle nudge towards this solution.

Uninstall **every bit** of NVIDIA software.

Install CUDA Toolkit 10.1. I did the Express Install of package **cuda_10.1.243_win10_network.exe**. *Any other version of CUDA 10.1 did not install correctly.*

Install CUDNN package 7.6. Extract all files from **cudnn-10.1-windows10-x64-v7.6.5.32** into the CUDA file structure (i.e. C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1)

Add these directories to your path variables (assuming that you did not alter the path during installation):

- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin
- C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\libnvvp

Reboot to initialize the Path variables.

Uninstall **all** tensorflow variants via PIP.

Install tensorflow 2.2 via PIP.

Then you can run the code below in bash to confirm that tensorflow is able to access your video card

```
# Check if tensorflow detects the GPU
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib

# Query tensorflow to see if it recognizes your GPU. This will output in the bash window
physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices()
GPU_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

print("physical_devices:", physical_devices)
print("Num GPUs:", len(GPU_devices))
```